# choppy transition with d3 area linearGradient

Tags: d3.js

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/6xq2wrfb/

It is probably something very simple I'm missing, but the graph starts with 60 seconds worth of data, then a new value is added every second. However, once the 60 second mark is reached, the graph becomes jerky and there is a gap. In order to update the graph, the translate offset I use is simply 60 seconds from the current time:

```
// Slide the area left

svg.select("path").transition().attr('transform', "translate(" + x(d3.time.second.offset(now, -60)) + ")");
```

But this fails once I hit the 60 second mark. For the life of me I can't figure this out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better version is here: https://jsfiddle.net/6xq2wrfb/1/

Basically, the following:

```
svg.select("path").transition().attr('transform', "translate(" + x(d3.time.second.offset(now, -60)) + ")");
```

now becomes:

```
svg.select("path").transition().attr('transform', "translate(" + x(data[0].time) + ",0)");
```